# Elastic search crashes with large data

Tags: php, sql, elasticsearch, elastica

So I've got a query that gives me as a result 500 hundred thousand data, and then I loop on it to add 20 documents for each result. Elastic search becomes not responding (the page keeps loading forever) and then gives me a `Couldn't connect to host, Elasticsearch down?` error. So while looping through all of the data, it crashes.

What could be the cause of Elastic search not to respond? Can't I use it to go over millions of information? Is it an Elasticserch configuration problem ?

Here is the code I'm using to loop :

```
$query = tep_db_query(" 
// Query giving 500k results
");

$achatsDocs = array();

while($array_collections = tep_db_fetch_array($query)){
    //looping the query


    $achatsDocs[] = new \Elastica\Document('', \Glam\HttpUtils::jsonEncode(
        array(
            // documents
        )
    ));
}

$achatsReportType->addDocuments($achatsDocs);
$achatsReportType->getIndex()->refresh();
```

I've been told to send a reasonable number of documents, e.g. 1000, per bulk request, not all of them at the same time. So I did this :

```
// while we didn't loop through every data
while(condition) {

    $query = tep_db_query("
        // get first/next 1000
    ");

    // put data inside first 1000
    while($array_collections = tep_db_fetch_array($query))

        $achatsDocs[] = new \Elastica\Document('', \Glam\HttpUtils::jsonEncode(
            array(
                // 20 documents
            )
        ));
    }

    $achatsReportType->addDocuments($achatsDocs);
    $achatsReportType->getIndex()->refresh();

    // go over next 1000
    $limit_start = $limit_start + 1000;
    $limit_end = $limit_end + 1000;


}
```

But it still crashes even after this, This does end up adding 70k results before crashing with this error :

`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Elastica\Exception\Connection\HttpException' with message 'Unknown error:52' in /var/www/vendor/ruflin/elastica/lib/Elastica/Transport/Http.php:167 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/vendor/ruflin/elastica/lib/Elastica/Request.php(171): Elastica\Transport\Http->exec(Object(Elastica\Request), Array) #1 /var/www/vendor/ruflin/elastica/lib/Elastica/Client.php(621): Elastica\Request->send() #2 /var/www/vendor/ruflin/elastica/lib/Elastica/Bulk.php(360): Elastica\Client->request('_bulk', 'PUT', '{"index":{"_ind...', Array) #3 /var/www/vendor/ruflin/elastica/lib/Elastica/Client.php(314): Elastica\Bulk->send() #4 /var/www/vendor/ruflin/elastica/lib/Elastica/Index.php(150): Elastica\Client->addDocuments(Array) #5 /var/www/vendor/ruflin/elastica/lib/Elastica/Type.php(196): Elastica\Index->addDocuments(Array) #6 /var/www/htdocs/adm54140/achatsReport_map.php(280): Elastica\Type->addDocuments(Array) #7 {main} thrown in /var/www/vendor/ruflin/elastica/lib/Elastica/Transport/Http.php on line 167 array(4) { ["code"]=> string(7) "E_ERROR" ["message"]=> string(928) "Uncaught exception 'Elastica\Exception\Connection\HttpException' with message 'Unknown error:52' in /var/www/vendor/ruflin/elastica/lib/Elastica/Transport/Http.php:167 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/vendor/ruflin/elastica/lib/Elastica/Request.php(171): Elastica\Transport\Http->exec(Object(Elastica\Request), Array) #1 /var/www/vendor/ruflin/elastica/lib/Elastica/Client.php(621): Elastica\Request->send() #2 /var/www/vendor/ruflin/elastica/lib/Elastica/Bulk.php(360): Elastica\Client->request('_bulk', 'PUT', '{"index":{"_ind...', Array) #3 /var/www/vendor/ruflin/elastica/lib/Elastica/Client.php(314): Elastica\Bulk->send() #4 /var/www/vendor/ruflin/elastica/lib/Elastica/Index.php(150): Elastica\Client->addDocuments(Array) #5 /var/www/vendor/ruflin/elastica/lib/Elastica/Type.php(196): Elastica\Index->addDocuments(Array) #6 /var/www/htdocs/adm54140/achatsReport_map.php(280): Elastica\Type->addDocuments(Array) #7 {main} thrown" ["file"]=> string(63) "/var/www/vendor/ruflin/elastica/lib/Elastica/Transport/Http.php" ["line"]=> int(167) }`

And then elasticsearch crashes.

Comment: And what do the Elasticsearch (not the app) logs say? They should give you more insight.

Answer (score 0):

Realtime pagination on "big" - subjective of course but I'd say that 500K+ results is "big enough" - result sets is notoriously hard on distributed data, also in Elasticsearch. There is however a solution: use the [Scroll API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html) to go through the results. It is better suited to your needs I think.

If you want to know why exactly your cluster crashed, take a look in the logs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer it might be useful when I search. My problem is that I'm not able to bulk index these documents, it crashes at that point.

Comment: Assuming you don't use the Scroll API, Elasticsearch tries to cram the whole result set into memory. Bulk indexing is also storing the request into memory so that combo might very well be the culprit. If you _do_ use the Scroll API, you're saving a significant amount of memory on the search side, leaving more for bulk indexing.

Comment: The indexing I'm doing isn't on the same page as the search, so they do not use the memory at the same time... I've been told to send a reasonable number of documents, e.g. 1000, per bulk request, not all of them at the same time. How to do just send 1k requests each? As I am looping over my query, how can I loop over it's 1k results, and then loop once again against it's next 1k results? Is my question clear? I'll update my question to give some code to show you.

Comment: I'm sorry, I misunderstood. I thought you got the results from Elasticsearch as well, that's why I suggested using the Scroll API  My bad. My only suggestion would be to look in the logs to find out what's gone wrong.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help anyway, the Scroll API is going to be useful nonetheless when I fix my problem :)

Comment: It depends on the cumulative size of the docs, here are some recommendations from elastic https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/indexing-performance.html

Comment: try increasing heap size allocation for elastic search , restart the cluster.

Answer (score 0):

I also had issues importing datasets bigger than 400k documents. 
I ended up using the BULK API, segmenting the data into groups of 1000 documents (as you were advised earlier).

[Elasticsearch Bulk API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html)

Maybe there are problems with Elastica client, I would advise you to save the chunks of 1000 into a json file with the following format:

```
{ "index" : { "_index" : "my_index", "_type" : "mappingType", "_id" :  "1234"} }
{ "name" : "John", "age" : 12, "_id" :  "1234"}
{ "index" : { "_index" : "my_index", "_type" : "mappingType", "_id" :  "1235"} }
{ "name" : "Maria", "age" : 17, "_id" :  "1235"}
```

And then create a .sh script containing one of the following lines for each json document:

```
curl -u user:"pass" -s -H "Content-Type: application/x-ndjson" -XPOST localhost:9200/_bulk --data-binary "@es_request1.json"
curl -u user:"pass" -s -H "Content-Type: application/x-ndjson" -XPOST localhost:9200/_bulk --data-binary "@es_request2.json"
```

Comment: { "index" : { } }

in case your index is same for every document , ids would be generated automatically.